# Recursively mutating values in a map of maps with Specter

Tags: recursion, clojure, specter

complete Clojure newbie here. This is a simple question, but I cant seem to get it:

Given that I have a nested hasmap of unknown depth, how do I use Specter's transform() to mutate the values of the data structure? I imagine a recursive-path is required here, but I cant get it to work. a working example is what I'm after and unfortunately, there isn't one in the docs.

(there is an [example](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter/wiki/Using-Specter-Recursively#recursively-navigate-to-every-map-in-a-map-of-maps) for set-val on a recursive map, but I don't know how to transform that into a transform use-case)

EDIT: More details were requested, so here they are:
I'm interested in a transform form that can mutate all the values of a nested maps - of any depth). for example, this transform would be able to increment all the values in the following maps (and any other nested map):

```
{:a 1 :b {:c 2 :d {:e 3}}} 
AND
{:a 1 :b {:c 2}}
AND
{:a 1}
```

the line of code I'm interested in might look sth like this:

```
(transform <missing selector here> inc data)
```

Comment: Even if you don't have it working, your code would help us understand what you are trying to do and work from there.

Comment: @cfrick I added more details. I reckon this should be clear enough to anyone who knows specter. there's not a lot of code to show - as is typical in clojure

Comment: the simplest one would be `(transform (walker number?) inc {:a 1 :b {:c 2 :d {:e 3}}})` . it might be too general, but it still solves the nested maps (as well as any nested structures) case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [linked example](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter/wiki/Using-Specter-Recursively#recursively-navigate-to-every-map-in-a-map-of-maps):

> ```
> (def MAP-NODES
>    (recursive-path [] p
>      (if-path map?
>        (continue-then-stay MAP-VALS p))))
> ```

```
(transform [MAP-NODES MAP-VALS number?] inc data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to always study the [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).  For something this simple, it might be easiest to just use `clojure.walk/postwalk`

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(dotest
  (let [data   {:a 1 :b {:c 2 :d {:e 3}}}
        result (walk/postwalk (fn [item]
                                (if (int? item)
                                  (inc item)
                                  item))
                 data)]
    (is= result {:a 2, :b {:c 3, :d {:e 4}}})))
```

For more advanced problems, you may be interested in the function [walk-with-parents](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.core#walk-with-parents), which allows you to inspect all items on the path from the root node through to the current node.